# Проблемы с EncodingFilter

Tags: java, html, filter

при разработке веб-приложения на java столкнулся с проблемой кодировки при отображении русских символов на страничке в бразуере.
[image: вывод]
Написал EncodingFilter и добавил его в web.xml. В чем может быть проблема?Почему не работает?

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>EncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>filters.EncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>requestEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>EncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

фильтр:

```
import javax.servlet.*;
```

import java.io.IOException;

public class EncodingFilter implements Filter {
    String encoding;

```
@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig){
    encoding = filterConfig.getInitParameter("requestEncoding");
    if (encoding == null) encoding = "UTF-8";
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    if (null == servletRequest.getCharacterEncoding()) {
        servletRequest.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);
    }else {
        servletResponse.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);
    }
    filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest,servletResponse);
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
}
```

}

Comment: А что за госпиталь вы пишете? У меня есть почти готовый веб проект с таким же именем ))

Comment: Программа конкретно для персонала госпиталя. Актеры: Админ,Доктор, Медсестра, Пациенты(пациент без роли,только упоминается для остальных). Назначение лекарств, процедур и т.п.

Comment: Ясно. Епам?)))))))))

Comment: Ага,они самые!)

Comment: Можно посмотреть ваш код?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно устанавливать кодировку и в `request`, и в `response`

```
@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig){
    encoding = filterConfig.getInitParameter("requestEncoding");
    if (encoding == null) encoding = "UTF-8";
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
// vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv    
String codeRequest = servletRequest.getCharacterEncoding();
    if (!encoding.equalsIgnoreCase(codeRequest)) {
        servletRequest.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);
        servletResponse.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);
    }
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest,servletResponse);
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
}
```

Также вы точно уверены, что только `*.html` должно фильтроваться?
Я бы сделал
`<url-pattern>/hospital/*</url-pattern>`

Comment: Решил проблему, но не таким способом. До этого устанавливал так. ничего не помогло. Но спасибо за ответ. Проблема была конкретно в Intelijidea, там надо было зайти в настройки проекта, encoding file и там убрать системную кодировку. Намучался сильно, со своим кодом пока не дошел до этого.